# Hyperbolicity of a fundamental group

Tags: geometric-group-theory, dg.differential-geometry

Let G be the fundamental group of a compact 3-manifold which supports on its interior a complete non positively curved Riemannian metric and is a cilinder near de metric. Is G hyperbolic?

Comment: What is the last part of the first sentence supposed to say?  At any rate, the fundamental group of a flat 3-torus is not hyperbolic.

Comment: You are right, then change nonpositively by negatively

Comment: It is a standard result in Riemannian geometry that the fundamental group of a compact Riemannian manifold with strictly negative curvature has hyperbolic fundamental group since the universal cover is $CAT(k)$ for some $k < 0$.  Does that answer your question, or are you asking about something else?

Comment: Actually I want to know if groups of that form (the way I difined in the first question) satisfy the k.theoretic farrell jones conjecture. I have another question. In the case of zero curvature what kind of groups may occur?

Comment: If you only require a negatively curved metric _on the interior_ then $G$ need not be hyperbolic. For example, the figure eight knot complement with the hyperbolic metric (a) has constant negative curvature and (b) is the interior of a compact three-manifold. But $G$ is not hyperbolic because the peripheral group is ${\mathbb{Z}}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this follows from the geometrization theorem. 
A negatively curved complete manifold  is atoroidal,
and the manifold is irreducible, so there is a complete
hyperbolic metric on the interior by geometrization.

In your comments, you ask about zero curvature. 
Then it is just a Euclidean manifold, with fundamental
group a Bieberbach group.

Comment: I think he means word-hyperbolic (I didn't say the question made any sense...)


Comment: I see Igor - I always confuse 3-manifolds and their fundamental groups. 
